# Pydantic2 computed field with validate_assignment=True

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a Pydantic V2 model with a field `total_amount` which should be automatically computed whenever `items` field changes:

```py
from typing import Self

import pydantic


class Calculation(pydantic.BaseModel):
    model_config = pydantic.ConfigDict(validate_default=True, validate_assignment=True)

    items: tuple[int, ...]
    total_amount: int = 0

    @pydantic.model_validator(mode="after")
    def set_amount(self) -> Self:
        self.total_amount = sum(self.items)
        return self


calc = Calculation(items=(1, 2, 3))
```

The problem is that because of `validate_assignment=True`, this code goes into infinite recursion:

```
  File "...py", line 14, in set_amount
    self.total_amount = sum(self.items)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 796, in __setattr__
    self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_assignment(self, name, value)
  File "...py", line 14, in set_amount
    self.total_amount = sum(self.items)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 796, in __setattr__
    self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_assignment(self, name, value)
  File "...py", line 14, in set_amount
    self.total_amount = sum(self.items)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 796, in __setattr__
    self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_assignment(self, name, value)
  File "...py", line 14, in set_amount
    self.total_amount = sum(self.items)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 767, in __setattr__
    elif not _fields.is_valid_field_name(name):
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_fields.py", line 277, in is_valid_field_name
    return not name.startswith('_')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I want the field to be computed so that when I dump the model instance to the database,
it to be up to date with `items`.

Is there a way to work around this? Like excluding a field from assignment validation? Or making it a simple property, but always dump it?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. Pydantic V2 for this [purpose](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/935) has a new decorator [`computed_field`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.computed_field):

```py
import pydantic


class Calculation(pydantic.BaseModel):
    model_config = pydantic.ConfigDict(validate_default=True, validate_assignment=True)

    items: tuple[int, ...]

    @pydantic.computed_field()
    @property
    def total_amount(self) -> int:
        return sum(self.items)


calc = Calculation(items=(1, 2, 3))
print(calc.total_amount)
calc.items += (4,)
print(calc.total_amount)
print(calc.model_dump())
```

Result:

```
6
10
{'items': (1, 2, 3, 4), 'total_amount': 10}
```

Comment: Surely you want @cached_property? (put a print statement inside the function to "log" when it actually runs.)